# Barra de Progresso em java

Tags: java

Boa tarde galera, tenho um projeto de iniciação cientifica na faculdade onde trabalhamos com java, nesse projeto criei um programa que realiza alguns cálculos, ele exibe os resultados calculados linha a linha até plotar um gráfico com os valores calculados no final do processo, gostaria agora de plotar uma barra de progresso que me mostre a percentagem dos cálculos já foram realizados, pesquisei como plotar essa barra mas nunca funciona, espero que algum de vocês consiga me ajudar nesse problema, obrigado!

```
       String energy = Energia.getText();   
            String Particula= (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();


            try {

            ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Users\\Juliana Cabral\\eclipse-workspace\\Gmf1\\src\\Gmf-igor.exe", energy, Particula);
            Process process = builder.start();
            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), 1);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (Exception ioe) {
            //ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou só te dar uma ideia ao invés de código...

Porque você não pega a **quantidade total de linhas** que tem no **documento** [Number of lines in a file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453018/number-of-lines-in-a-file-in-java) e a **posição da linha atual** que está **sendo lida**, tratando essa relação como **porcentagem** e a cada porcentagem nova ele **adiciona** string '#' numa barra feita com System.out.println por exemplo:

[ #########################.......................................... ]

Se tiver utilizando algum framework de UI faria de acordo com o estilo dele, por exemplo dividiria o espaço em duas cores, e a cada nova iteração o *width* de um dos espaços (cor) aumentaria...